# Why can't i execute run-mozilla.sh?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, .sh

I have downloaded latest version of mozila-firefox from http://tinyurl.com/lm4449e . Try to install it by running following commands.

```
cd Dowloads
tar xjf firefox-38.0.1.tar.bz2
cd firefox
chmod +x run-mozilla.sh
./run-mozilla.sh
```

But i am getting an error that "run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute"

Comment: Did you try `bash run-mozilla.sh` instead of `./run-mozilla.sh`?

Comment: @Helio : Yes, i did, same error.

Comment: You can install it easily by `sudo apt-get install firefox`

Comment: Can you upload the output of `cat run-mozilla.sh` to http://paste.ubuntu.com or record it with asciinema?

Comment: @Helio: here is the output of `cat run-mozilla.sh` http://paste.ubuntu.com/11223005/

Comment: @NewUSer : I know i can install it by `sudo apt-get install firefox` but that way i am getting `firefox version 28` whereas i want to use the latest version of it. Even i tried to update it after installing version 28, but i did not work out.

Comment: What the output of `ls`?

Comment: do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` . V 38 is already in sources now

Comment: @Helio : here is output of `ls` http://paste.ubuntu.com/11223074/

Comment: Did you try `./firefox` or `./firefox-bin`?

Comment: @NewUSer : As i told you earlier. I tried to update it, but it didn't work out. I tried again and same result :(

Comment: @Shravan40 check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can install it using apt-get, You should update your source list.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but if you want to install it manually, here what you should do;

Download then extract as you did already

move the extracted folder to /opt

```
sudo mv firefox* /opt/firefox38
```

If you already had a previous Firefox version installed in the /opt directory, remove it with the following command:

```
sudo mv /opt/firefox /opt/old_firefox
```

Set up symbolic links

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-old

sudo ln -s /opt/firefox38/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

if everything goes well then you can delete firefox-old in /usr/bin and old_firefox dolder in /opt